# Fill data in specific rows from json with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I want to fill json data in multiple specific rows.
Json:

```
   {"locations":[{"Location":"27|","Name":"Al Jamia Distric B ,"branch":"23","MaleStaff":"20","FemaleStaff":"30"},{"Location":"26|","Name":"Al Kharj Branch ","branch":"146","MaleStaff":"40","FemaleStaff":"50"}]}
```

Html:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="branch" value="23"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="male"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="female"/>
</td>
```

......

so i want to fill data in male and female class where "class branch value is 23 in html input tag which is equal to branch value in json".
Help me out

Comment: i have tried http://jsfiddle.net/vzL9mwnz/   ,  but its not working for me

Comment: _"have tried jsfiddle.net/vzL9mwnz , but its not working for me"_ ? `$('.male').append(a.locations[i].MaleStaff);` appear to append "20" , "40" to `.male` element at http://jsfiddle.net/vzL9mwnz/ ?

Comment: 20 should be append in row of 23 and 40 on row of 146

Comment: I would suggest using D3 instead of jQuery. D3 is especially good for binding data to html/svg elements. Check out http://d3js.org

Comment: can u share me link related to my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `<tbody>` parent element to `<tr>` elements with `<table>` element ; using only `for` loop to iterate `a.locations` , filter `input` utilizing `[value=" + a.locations[i].Code + "]` attribute selector ; select `.parent()` of filtered `input` , `.male` element child within `.next()` `td` element ; `.append()` `a.locations[i].MaleStaff` to selected filtered `.male` element

```
var a = $.parseJSON(data);

for (var i = 0; i < a.locations.length; i++) {
    $("input[value=" + a.locations[i].Code + "]")
    .parent().next("td").find(".male")
    .append(a.locations[i].MaleStaff);
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vzL9mwnz/1/

Comment: @XeeShan Invalid `html` , `tr` elements within `table` not have `tbody` parent element at  http://jsfiddle.net/vzL9mwnz/2/ . See updated post , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

Comment: how i will insert value in 3rd td or 2nd td

Comment: if my html structure is like this http://jsfiddle.net/vzL9mwnz/5/
then how can i insert

Comment: @XeeShan In future , perhaps consider including all portions of Question at original post ; or ask new Question where _"if my html structure is like"_ http://jsfiddle.net/vzL9mwnz/5/ not appear at original post ? Try `.nextAll("td:has(.PC)").find(".PC")` http://jsfiddle.net/vzL9mwnz/6/